# Downloading the current location from server

Tags: android, gps

I am making a GPS application. My current location is continuously being uploaded to the server. I need to retrieve the latest location from the server from any android device.The server however contains the previous locations as well.

I am able to send my location to the server, but I am facing problem in receiving the current location.

I am proceeding in the following order

1. getting my current location.
2. sending my current location to the server.
3. receiving the current location from the server from any android device.

I am getting stuck in the 3rd part.

Comment: If you want to receving location from the server you should have web-service for it like REST

Comment: can you please elaborate as i have no idea about it.